# Find a conformal map

Tags: complex-analysis

I am looking for a conformal map that sends $A=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|>1, Re(Z)>0,Im(z)>0\}$ to the unit disk.
My first step is to find a conformal map that sends A to a quarter disk. I guess $f(z)=1/\bar{z}$ will do it. Is it correct?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your function $f(z) = 1/\bar z$ works. This gives the right upper unit disc. These are the complex numbers with argument less then $\pi/2$:
$$f(A) = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1, Re(z)>0, Im(z)>0\}=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1, 0<\text{Arg}(z)<\pi/2\}$$
So to get all of the unit disk we have to multiply the arguments by 4, this can be done by raising it to the 4th power:
$$g(z) = f(z)^4 = 1/z^4$$
Raising to the power of 4 also raises de modulus of the numbers to that power, but this will stay in the unit disk and it's invers (taking 4th root) also stays in the unit disc so this doesn't matter

Comment: I first thought about 1/z, but it will map 1+i to 1/(1+i), which is in the third quadrant?

Comment: @WLET You are right, $1/z$ inverts the modulus but also negates the argument, and indeed the conjugation solves that, I will edit my answer

Comment: I am sorry, 1/(1+i) is in fourth quadrant